# Show that $X^TX(X^TX)^g$ is a projection onto the column space of $X^T$

Tags: matrices, projection

Show that
$$X^TX(X^TX)^g $$ is a projection onto the column space of $X^T$

I'm having a bit of trouble getting this, I am aware of the three conditions to prove that it is a projection but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: I am assuming by $(X^tX)^g$ you mean the generalized inverse of $X^TX$?

Comment: Yep that's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be the generalized inverse of $A$. Then $AGA=A$. Therefore,
$$(AG)^2=(AGA)G=AG$$
Hence $AG$ is idempotent.

For any two matrices $A$ and $B$, $\mathcal{C}(AB)\subseteq\mathcal{C}(A)$. Hence $\mathcal{C}(AG)\subseteq\mathcal{C}(A)$. However
$$\mathrm{rank}(AG)\ge\mathrm{rank}(AGA)=\mathrm{rank}(A)\ge\mathrm{rank}(AG)$$
Hence we have $\mathrm{rank}(A)=\mathrm{rank}(AG)$ and hence $\mathcal{C}(AG)=\mathcal{C}(A)$.

This proves that $AG$ is the projector matrix for $\mathcal{C}(A)$.

Now we need to show that $\mathcal{C}(X^TX)=\mathcal{C}(X^T)$. Of course we know $\mathcal{C}(X^TX)\subseteq\mathcal{C}(X^T)$.

Now $$X^TXx=0\implies x^TX^TXx=0\implies(Xx)^T(Xx)=0\implies Xx=0$$
$$Xx=0\implies X^TXx=0$$
Hence $\mathrm{nullity}(X^TX)=\mathrm{nullity}(X)$. So $$\mathrm{rank}(X^TX)=\mathrm{rank}(X)=\mathrm{rank}(X^T)$$
Thus we have $\mathcal{C}(X^TX)=\mathcal{C}(X^T)$.

Comment: How are you able to get rid of the generalized inverse when you say C(X^TX)=C(X^T)?

Comment: I am not getting  rid of the generalized inverse. I first proved that for any matrix $A$ with generalized inverse $G$, $AG$ projects onto $\mathcal{C}(A)$. Putting $A=X^TX$, we get that $X^TX(X^TX)^g$ projects onto $\mathcal{C}(X^TX)$ and then showed that $\mathcal{C}(X^TX)=\mathcal{C}(X^T)$.